# How can I delete the resource-level permission in all Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I delete the resource-level permission in all Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resources?
For example, a compute VM instance is shared to another GCP user without assigning an IAM role. Is there way using the GCP SDK terminal command or GCP console to get rid of the resource-level permissions?

I tried the terminal command below but is not working

```
 gcloud resource-manager members remove user@gmail.com --project=project_name --member-type="roles/viewer"
```

Comment: For resources that support IAM policies, you must manage each one. AFAIK there is no global command to delete a user from ORG, Folder, Project, and resources. Note: I do not recognize the command in your post. Did you make up that command? The group `members` is invalid.

Comment: I thought I can come up with a single command to remove all iam policy binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762302/how-can-i-delete-the-resource-level-permission-in-all-google-cloud-platform-gcp#comment137092624_77762302):

> For resources that support IAM policies, you must manage each one.

That would mean:

- Determine the specific [GCP resources](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager#features) (e.g., Compute VM instances, Cloud Storage buckets) for which you want to remove permissions.
- Use the `gcloud` command or GCP Console to list the current IAM policies for each resource.
- Remove the user or role from the [IAM policy of each resource](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-types-with-policies).

For instance, for a [Compute VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances), you would:

- [List the IAM policy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-iam-policy) for the instance:

  ```bash
  gcloud compute instances get-iam-policy INSTANCE_NAME --project=PROJECT_ID --format=json
  ```
- Remove the User from the IAM Policy, by creating a modified IAM policy that excludes the user or role you want to remove.
  Open `policy.json` in a text editor. You will see a JSON structure with several bindings. Each binding associates a role with a list of members (users, service accounts, etc.).
  Locate the binding for the role that the user is part of, and remove the user from the `members` list.

  For example, if `user@gmail.com` has the role of `roles/viewer`, find and edit the corresponding section:

  ```json
  {
      "bindings": [
          {
              "role": "roles/viewer",
              "members": [
                  "user:user@gmail.com"
                  // other members
              ]
          }
          // other bindings
      ]
  }
  ```

  Remove `"user:user@gmail.com"` from the `members` array.
- [Apply the new policy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-iam-policy) to the resource.

  ```bash
  gcloud compute instances set-iam-policy INSTANCE_NAME policy.json --project=PROJECT_ID
  ```

Again, you would have to repeat this process for each resource type and instance, since there is no global command to remove a user from all resources at once.

---

[John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)  suggests a paragraph on searching for which resources have bindings:

To effectively manage IAM policies and permissions in GCP, it is also important to identify which resources have specific IAM bindings. That can be done using the [Cloud Asset API](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest), which allows custom queries to search IAM policies and resource metadata within a project, folder, or organization.

1. **Search IAM Policies**:

   - Use the Cloud Asset API to search for IAM policies across your GCP resources.
   - Before beginning, make sure the Cloud Asset API is enabled for your project, and you have the necessary permissions.
   - You can construct queries to filter IAM policies based on specific criteria, like roles, members, conditions, and associated resources. The query syntax allows for both exact and partial matches.
   - Examples of queries include searching for policies related to a specific user (e.g., `policy:"user:amy@mycompany.com"`) or a particular role (e.g., `roles:roles/owner`).
   - For detailed information on constructing queries, refer to [Searching IAM policies in GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies).
2. **Search Resources:**

   - Similarly, you can query resource metadata using the Cloud Asset API.
   - That enables you to find resources based on specific attributes, types, or locations.
   - The search can be refined using various filters and query syntax, which is particularly useful for large-scale environments with numerous resources.
   - For more guidance on querying resource metadata, refer to [Searching resources in GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources).

With that, your IAM management workflow will benefit from a robust process for identifying and updating permissions across your GCP environment.

Comment: +1 - your answer could be the start of a good article on IAM policies for managing resources. The only improvement that I can think of is to add a paragraph on searching for which resources have bindings. https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies and https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources

Comment: @JohnHanley Good point. I have updated the answer with that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Additional resources to map the GCP Asset Type and GCP Resource Name vs the gcloud and bq command. This will help to identify where to get the required gcloud and bq system arguments needed such as instance name, zone, region, etc.

https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/resource-name-format

https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_remove-iam-policy-binding